# How could I 'hide away' a complex group_by clause in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails 3 app, I'm running a somewhat complex group_by and am curious if I can hide it away elsewhere, much like one can hide away ActiveRecord conditions in a scope. I realize group_by is an operation on an Enumerable, so scopes don't apply here, but my question is if there's a way to create a shorthand for this in a comparable way:

```
@launches_and_finales = Show.launches_and_finales.sort_by { |s| 
   (s.run_starts_on && 
   ((Date.today - 3.days)..(Date.today + 3.days)) === s.run_starts_on) ? 
   s.run_starts_on : s.run_ends_on }
```

Side note: I realize `3.days.ago..3.days.from_now` would be more succinct, but there's a [bug in Ruby 1.9.2](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5794-using-include-on-a-time-range-yields-unhappy-results) that triggers an endless loop when I use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement this using one of these two strategies:

1. Wrap the logic within an association extension
2. Rails 3's Arel could help you wrap that into a standard method call

   class Show

   def self.launches_and_finales

   ```
   where(["run_starts_on between ? and ? or ...", Time.now - 3.day, Time.now + 3.days])
   ```

   end

   end

Comment: I hadn't thought about doing more complex logic at the Model layer. I must have only considered scopes with their limitations here, but of course I can just add a whole new method. I don't think 2 will do the trick though, since it's the more complex group_by that I'm after, not just the filter.